# Getting email Notification Folder count

Tags: powershell, scripting

With this powershell script i'm able get file count on inside a folder

```
Get-ChildItem D:\ -Recurse -File | Measure-Object | %{$_.Count}
```

here is the script sending email.

```
$Count = Get-ChildItem D:\ -Recurse -File | Measure-Object | %{$_.Count} 
$Status= $Event.Message 
$From = "sender@sender.com"
$To = "receiver"
$SMTPServer = "smtp"
$SMTPPort = "587"
$Username = "email@email.us"
$Password = "password"
$Subject = "$computer,Files count"
$Body = "Number of Files is $Count |D drive test "
$smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SMTPServer, $SMTPPort);
$smtp.EnableSSL = $false
$smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $Password);
$smtp.Send($From, $To, $subject, $body); 
$computer = "$env:computername
```

But the output is simply plain text **Number of Files is 58 |D drive test**

can we have it to alert us with some more text like If file count is mismatch it should consider a warning like "number of files is 60 which is large" or if it gets less it should be critical  and error.

Comment: I'm confused.  The body of the text is what you specifically set it to be.  If you want it to have more text, why not set it?

Comment: This is one awesome piece of software directorymonitor see this screenshot can powershell do this? https://directorymonitor.com/images/features/main_text_small.png

Comment: I think it wll be tough for powershell to have such features I found a portable free version for directory monitor the best

Comment: Sure, PowerShell can get that information, but you'd have to set it up to run on a schedule, and store the results somewhere for comparison during the next run. Probably beyond your skills if you're not sure why the message body isn't more than what you set.

Comment: This is a programming question, not a sysadmin question, so I'm voting to move it to StackOverflow.

Comment: if this is programming then all scripting should be moved as well.

Answer (score 1):

you have comparison operators:

- `-lt` = lower than
- `-gt` = greater than
- `-ge` = greater or equal
- `-le` = less or equal
- `-eq` = equal

And you have `if`, `elseif` and `else`

with that you can change your body message (as suggested in the answer of DarkMoon)

```
if ($count -le '50') {
    $Body = 'your text'
}
elseif (($count -gt '50') -and ($count -le '100')) {
    $Body = 'your text'
}
elseif (($count -gt '100') -and ($count -le '500')) {
    $Body = 'your text'
}
else {
    $Body = 'your text'
}
```

Comment: Can we also Mo niter size?, directory report was good but it wll not monitor size and count but will send report which file got deleted which was best.

Comment: @jacksh I don't get what you're asking. You need the size of your D:\ Drive or of every file in D:\ ? and you need to count how many objects are in D:\?

Comment: Size + number i was able to get script which determines size

$folder = "C:\myfolder\"
$folderSize = ( Get-ChildItem $folder -Recurse -Force | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum ).Sum
If ( $folderSize -lt 1KB ) { $folderSizeOutput = "$("{0:N2}" -f $folderSize) B" }
ElseIf ( $folderSize -lt 1MB ) { $folderSizeOutput = "$("{0:N2}" -f ($folderSize / 1KB)) KB" }
ElseIf ( $folderSize -lt 1GB ) { $folderSizeOutput = "$("{0:N2}" -f ($folderSize / 1MB)) MB" }
ElseIf ( $folderSize -lt 1TB ) { $folderSizeOutput = "$("{0:N2}" -f ($folderSize / 1GB)) GB" }
Write-Output $folderSizeOutput

Answer (score 0):

For the warning, it'd be simply something along the lines of:

```
if ($Count -lt 60) {
  $Body = "Number of Files is low at $Count |D drive test "
} else {
  $Body = "Number of Files is $Count which is large |D drive test "
}
```

Comment: Thanks DarlMoon Can we also Moniter size simon, directory report was good but it wll not monitor size and count but will send report which file got deleted which was best